# Azure Bot Service handle internally the refresh token mechanism?

Tags: botframework

I have a question about this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication

Imagine that I want to consume the MSGraph API then clearly I can use the method context.GetUserTokenAsync(ConnectionName) and start the authentication flow in order to grab a valid token, however, what happen when the token is expired?
The GetUserTokenAsync return always a valid and refreshed token or should I call other methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using v3 or v4?

Comment: What we recommend in this situation is before calling anything that would require a token to execute, send the OAuth prompt again.  If the user has a valid token the actual OAuth card will not be sent and your process will execute as normal.  If the token is expired and unable to be refreshed for some reason the user will be prompted to log in again. in general, yes the bot service will handle refresh for you.

Comment: Thanks I'm using the V4 with Nodejs and I'm using this function

    static prompt(connectionName) {
        const loginPrompt = new OAuthPrompt(LOGIN_PROMPT,
            {
                connectionName: connectionName,
                text: 'Login rewuired',
                title: 'Login',
                timeout: 30000
            });
        return loginPrompt;
    }

Comment: As long as you do not do something like store the token locally, you will not need to refresh the token.  You are better off calling the prompt rather than `getUserToken` that way if the user does need a new token it will automatically get the new one rather than return an expired token.

Comment: Thanks @JasonSowers for your clarification ;-)